# A person who talks with care

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a guy who talks so elegantly, when he talks he knows what he is saying; he takes care of each word out of his mouth, his words shows his high personality etc ... and what would be the adjective for such words said? e.g. "thoughtfully put", " elegantly said" etc ..

Comment: The word is 'articulate'

Comment: I know articulate or eloquent but it doesnt mean he is very attentive to what he says, it means he just talks with nice words. I mean, kids dont know how to talk with strangers, sometimes they just make slip of tongue and put all in embarrassment. A mature guy doesnt do this. A President talks with great care bcos any single word can raise unrest..

Comment: Just call him a [***carefully-spoken** man*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22carefully-spoken+man%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). Note there can be a difference between "elegant" speech (from articulate/poetic speakers) and "careful, thoughtful" (from cautious speakers, presidents, etc., who might think carefully before using "weasel words").

Comment: I like " carefully-spoken" ... will do , thnx

Comment: It sounds as if you are looking for 'an erudite person who is guarded in what he says'.

Comment: *Carefully-spoken* seems too wordy, especially when several single-word answers abound.

Comment: I can think of words to describe the caution and care (circumspect, diplomatic, prudent) but I can't think of anything that also encompasses elegance (articulate, eloquent). "Carefully-spoken" doesn't sound natural to me so if it were me, I'd go with articulate and circumspect together.

Comment: ¿n ƃuᴉʇɹʍ dʇs zןd n pɔ?

Comment: You can say he *speaks **deliberately***.

Comment: I think "rare" is probably the best term.

Comment: *He is a careful speaker.* (That's what I'd say.) One form of this is *He chooses his words carefully*, but that is only about word choice, and it can have a negative connotation of being afraid to say what he really feels.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure there is a single word which would capture all the nuances which you are after. **Precise** probably comes close, but has overtones of pedantry (which I think you don't want). Some combination of **precise**, **articulate** and **sensitive** might be what you are after. I would agree with you that **eloquence** probably veers more into the realm of artistry-with-words than you would like.

Comment: can I say, the guy is precise or a precise guy  ..never heard  it ..

Comment: Of course, you can say someone is/was *precise*, with regard to their speech or delivery, etc.

Comment: +1 for *articulate*. In my opinion, there is no need to combine with *precise* and *sensitive*. *Articulate* has a strong connotation of precise. The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=articulate&allowed_in_frame=0) of *articulate* might shed some light on its particular strength for this application.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be offering a **fastidious speaker**

> [Garner on Language and Writing: Selected Essays and ... -](https://books.google.ca/books?id=9_PdSrVNTUUC&pg=PA516&dq=%22fastidious%20speaker%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IKUVVevcKoW1sQSk4YLwAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22fastidious%20speaker%22&f=false)  Page
>   516 Bryan A. Garner - 2009
>
> To select one of several examples, in the days when aggravate was
>   first coming to be widely used for "irritate, annoy," **the fastidious
>   speaker or writer** could either combat the word's debasement and use
>   it correctly or seek refuge in exacerbate.

as well as [**an*l**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=sc-7AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT31&dq=%22fastidious%22%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zaYVVbiTEorfsASJ-YGYCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22fastidious%22%20slang&f=false) (sorry, but ...)

Also, more positive:

> Adam Smith: An Enlightened Life Nicholas Phillipson - 2010
>
> ... thus bestows upon the whole species those names which it had been
>   taught to apply to two individuals.' In the same way **we say of a
>   great orator that he is a Cicero** or a great scientist that he is a
>   Newton.

Comment: Fastidious has a negative connotation which OP , apparently, is not looking for!!

Comment: An elegant speaker seems more likely to have an **oral** rather than an anal fixation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**silver-tongued** *adjective*: marked by convincing and eloquent expression “a *silver–tongued* politician”; see, Merriam-Webster [**silver-tongued**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silver-tongued)

Answer (score 1):

I like *laconic*.  A laconic person's speech could be described as *concise*, *fastidious*, *precise*, or my personal favorite, *economical*.

(Of course, you could bellow, "This!  Is! [Laconia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laconia)!" if you wanted to make an obscure joke.)

Answer (score 1):

**circumspect** (adj.)-thinking carefully about possible risks before doing or saying something. (Merriam-Webster.com)

Answer (score 0):

I would describe him as *well-spoken*

If I were describing his speech I would use *definite*/*definitive* or *lucid*/*clear*